# The suffix for number of people reached should be M, not m

Tags: bug, reputation, people-reached

`~2.0m people reached` on my tab. So I've reached 2/1000ths of a person. Good to know ;-)

Comment: No, it means that you only reached people that are around 2 meters tall.

Comment: Or 2 meters of people, stacked like logs.